# Why does pandas multi-index dataframe slicing seem inconsistent?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multi-index

Why is it that when slicing a multi-index dataframe, you can get away with simpler syntax as long as you are slicing the level-0 index?  Here is an example dataframe:

```
           hi
a b   c      
1 foo baz   0
      can   1
  bar baz   2
      can   3
2 foo baz   4
      can   5
  bar baz   6
      can   7
3 foo baz   8
      can   9
  bar baz  10
      can  11
```

These work:

```
df.loc[1, 'foo', :]
df.loc[1, :, 'can']
```

While this doesn't:

```
df.loc[:, 'foo', 'can']
```

Forcing me to use one of these instead:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 'foo', 'can'), :]
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'foo', 'can'], :]
```

Below are the same examples but with more detail:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'can']], names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
data = np.arange(len(ix))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ix, columns=['hi'])
print df

           hi
a b   c      
1 foo baz   0
      can   1
  bar baz   2
      can   3
2 foo baz   4
      can   5
  bar baz   6
      can   7
3 foo baz   8
      can   9
  bar baz  10
      can  11

In [2]: df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print df.loc[1, 'foo', :]

           hi
a b   c      
1 foo baz   0
      can   1

In [3]: print df.loc[1, :, 'can']

           hi
a b   c      
1 bar can   3
  foo can   1

In [4]: print df.loc[:, 'foo', 'can']

KeyError: 'the label [foo] is not in the [columns]'

In [5]: print df.loc[(slice(None), 'foo', 'can'), :]

           hi
a b   c      
1 foo can   1
2 foo can   5
3 foo can   9

In [6]: print df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'foo', 'can'], :]

           hi
a b   c      
1 foo can   1
2 foo can   5
3 foo can   9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three examples are technically ambiguous, but in the first two, Pandas guesses your intent correctly.  Since slicing rows, selecting columns (i.e., `df.loc[:, columns]`) is a common idiom, the inference seems to pick that interpretation.

The inference is kind of messy, so I think it's much better to be explicit.  It's not that much extra typing if you alias `IndexSlice`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[1, 'foo'], :]
df.loc[idx[1, :, 'can'], :]
df.loc[idx[:, 'foo', 'can'], :]
```

Comment: Why is `df.loc[:, columns]` a common idiom when `df[columns]` seems to do the same thing?  I'm probably missing some nuance.

Comment: It usually does the same thing...except when it doesn't due to fallbacks.  There's an issue on the github that enumerates all the possibilities - https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9595 - as noted there, it's a bit of a mess, at this point primarily for backwards compat.